# Android webview ui

Tags: android, user-interface, webview

I'm beating my head against the wall here. I'm simply creating a `WebView` that also has the capability to go forward, refresh and back. I've been playing with the Android dev kit for two weeks now and feel I'm fairly far however I can't seem to solve this problem no matter what I do.

I simply want to press the menu button and get a "Back", "Refresh" and "Forward" option. Thus far I have managed to have the buttons appear in my `WebView` however they perform no action, as in nothing happens. Any solution for the newbie [who has searched everywhere] would be great.

My code is included below:
**`XXXXX.java`**

```
package com.AFMoB.XXXXX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class XXXXX extends Activity { //** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public WebView webView;    //DECLARE webview variable outside of onCreate function so we can access it in other functions (menu)

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Part of the progress bar system for future   use-->   this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); // Create an instance of WebView and set it to the layout component created with id webview in main.xml
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enables Java
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // Opens web links clicked by user in the webview
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                        String description, String failingUrl) { // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.afdc.energy.gov/afdc/locator/m/stations/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); // Add menu items, second value is the id, use this in the onCreateOptionsMenu
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Back");
        menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Refresh");
        menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Forward");
        return true; // End of menu configuration
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuItem item) { // Called when you tap a menu item
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1: //If the ID equals 1 , go back
                webView.canGoBack();
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.back); // Occurs after tapping the back menu item
                return true;
            case 2: //If the ID equals 2 , go refresh
                webView.reload();
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.refresh);
                return true;
            case 3: //If the ID equals 3 , go forward
                webView.canGoForward();
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.forward);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { // Enables browsing to previous pages with the hardware back button
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) { // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }    // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**`main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"></WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="30" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.AFMoB.XXXXX"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <activity
            android:name=".XXXXX"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where you have commented that
 "// Called when you tap a menu item"
You are calling onCreateOptionsMenu,
it should be

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This worked perfectly. I also removed the lines 'item.setIcon(R.drawable.back);' because I found using my own icons was useless. I have tried everything to get my 'forward' and 'back' to work but have been very unsuccessful.

Refresh is working [I figured it out by changing the method to read 'webView.reload();' instead of 'webView.refresh();' 

Can anyone assist with the forward and back? I have tried 'forward', 'canGoForward' and 'goForward' as well as 'back', 'canGoBack' and 'goBack'. There are no error codes however none of those methods actually do anything.

Comment: If the answer has solved your question, do check the answer as right. And for other things, ask as a separate question, those who have knowledge about it, will be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help again, I did get the forward and back to work!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
case 1:
if (webView.canGoBack())
webView.goBack();
```

instead of

```
case 1:
webView.canGoBack();
```